# Android: creating two linearlayout in single relative layout with on click button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

In my single screen android project(using only one XML file) when i press button1 then linerlayout1 is open and when i press button2 then linearlayout2 is open.my button1 and button2 is placed in linearlayout3.can it works??if yes then how??
thanks in advance.

```
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

       <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

      <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/linearLayout1" />

     <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/linearLayout1" />



     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Button1" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Button2" />


   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/linearLayout2" />

    <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/linearLayout2" />


        </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: onClick() setVisibility(View.GONE); could do the job. Just give ids to your linear layouts.

Comment: imho, it will be better if instead 1 visible and 2 invisible panels in one window, you will use Fragment and change them dynamically http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very simple:

Use the `android:Visibility` XML tag initially, and when each respective button is pressed, you'd obtain your reference to the `LinearLayout`s, and set their visibility to `VISIBLE` or `GONE` in code.

Note: you want to use `GONE` rather than `INVISIBILE` as `INVISIBILE` will still take up screen space, so there'll be a large chunk of blank space where it was before, whereas I assume you want them in place of each other

Comment: sorry sir.i did not get you.i m beginner in android.can u give me proper java activity code how about how to use linear layout and button?

Answer (score 0):

in the layout xml of linear layout 1 and 2, use

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

From code

```
LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
```

you can use the following to make it visible

```
l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and to hide it

```
l1. setVisibility(View.GONE):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with the "setVisibility" property of your layout.
In the "onCreate()" method you can do something like this

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And then on your button press

```
layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: thank you sir.it successfully works but how to invisible linearlayout1 when i pressed button2(linearlayout2 pop up)??

Comment: when you press button2 you must do the following: layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);